# How to deal with build problems of ActiveState for its ppm?

Tags: windows, perl, soap, build, activestate

I use community version of ActiveState Perl under Windows and therefore need to either keep older versions around or use the most current releases. Problem is that I often found that some of my used packages do not build on their current Perl distributions, some of those build problems get fixed "sometime". Currently [SOAP::Lite](https://code.activestate.com/ppm/SOAP-Lite/) is marked as to not build successfully, looks like because of some [missing dependencies](https://code.activestate.com/ppm/Crypt-SSLeay/), though the tests of SOAP::Lite itself seems to pass. Only waiting until this gets fixed doesn't seem like a good solution to me, so I wonder:

Is there any known best practice how to deal with such build problems regarding ActiveState? Is there any bug tracker or else to get them having a look at those problems? Would there be any chance to provide patches, if one would have a solutions for some problems? Or would one need to always contact the project for the package not building? Because some problems are clearly related to ActiveStates environment.

I couldn't find anything to contact Activestate or whatever regarding such build problems. Seems to me the only possible way is to buy support.

Comment: If it won't build from source, you may find that using `ppm` to install it will work.

Comment: ppm itself is failing to build the package and therefore doesn't provide it, as my links show.

Comment: OK, fair enough. I usually find between `ppm` and `cpan install` I can get _most_ stuff working, But generally I think ActiveState aren't really interested unless you're a paying customer.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, `Crypt::SSLeay` fails to build because it cannot deduce where ActiveState keeps OpenSSL when building PPM modules. I do not know why [SOAP::Lite declares a dependency on Crypt::SSLeay](http://www.nu42.com/2014/08/dont-declare-dependency-on-cryptssleay.html), but, unfortunately it does.

So, the package manager fails to package the module.

Since it doesn't look like there are any problems building [SOAP::Lite](https://metacpan.org/pod/SOAP::Lite) itself, do download the package, extract, and do the

```
C:\...> perl Makefile.PL
C:\...> dmake
C:\...> dmake test
```

and finally, if tests pass,

```
dmake install
```

dance.

The module's `Makefile.PL` is interesting because it declares explicit dependencies on both `IO::Socket::SSL` *and* `Crypt::SSLeay` when all it needs is to recommend a dependency on `LWP::Protocol::https`.

I should point out that [IO::Socket::SSL is what you want](http://www.nu42.com/2014/04/does-your-code-really-depend-on.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the intention of my question is not how to make it on my own, but instead how to deal with ActiveState. They should fix their build setup and maybe they just don't know about the problem or they are known to not care or whatever... I just can't find any info.